# elixir phoenix - protocol error during testing

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a simple data:

```
{
    "name" : "example task",
    "description":"example description",
    "type" : "task",
    "details" : {
        "__type__":"task",
        "amount":20.00,
    },
    "publish" : true
}
```

When I test my API with postman, everything works. But when I write a unit test for controller, I got this error:

```
  1) test create_task: assign task (OkBackendWeb.TaskControllerTest)
     test/ok_backend_web/controllers/task_controller_test.exs:87
     ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for 20.0 of type Float. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): Any, Atom, BitString, Integer, Map
     code: conn = post(conn, Routes.item_path(conn, :create_all, @create_attrs))
     stacktrace:
       (phoenix 1.5.13) lib/phoenix/param.ex:121: Phoenix.Param.Any.to_param/1
       (plug 1.12.1) lib/plug/conn/query.ex:275: Plug.Conn.Query.encode_value/2
       (plug 1.12.1) lib/plug/conn/query.ex:246: Plug.Conn.Query.encode_pair/3
       (plug 1.12.1) lib/plug/conn/query.ex:262: anonymous fn/3 in Plug.Conn.Query.encode_kv/3
       (elixir 1.13.1) lib/enum.ex:1213: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.flat_map/2
       (stdlib 3.14) maps.erl:233: :maps.fold_1/3
       (elixir 1.13.1) lib/enum.ex:2408: Enum.flat_map/2
       (plug 1.12.1) lib/plug/conn/query.ex:266: Plug.Conn.Query.encode_kv/3
       (plug 1.12.1) lib/plug/conn/query.ex:262: anonymous fn/3 in Plug.Conn.Query.encode_kv/3
       (elixir 1.13.1) lib/enum.ex:4086: Enum.flat_map_list/2
       (elixir 1.13.1) lib/enum.ex:4087: Enum.flat_map_list/2
       (plug 1.12.1) lib/plug/conn/query.ex:266: Plug.Conn.Query.encode_kv/3
       (plug 1.12.1) lib/plug/conn/query.ex:204: Plug.Conn.Query.encode/2
       (ok_backend 0.1.0) lib/ok_backend_web/router.ex:1: OkBackendWeb.Router.Helpers.segments/5
       (ok_backend 0.1.0) lib/ok_backend_web/router.ex:1: OkBackendWeb.Router.Helpers.item_path/3
       test/ok_backend_web/controllers/task_controller_test.exs:91: (test)
```

this is my test exs:

```
defmodule ExampleWeb.TaskControllerTest do
  use ExampleWeb.ConnCase

  alias Example.Users
  alias Example.Items

  @create_attrs %{
    "name" => "milk with cow",
    "description"=> "cow are cute.",
    "type" => "task",
    "details" => %{
        "amount"=> 20.00,
    },
    "publish" => true
}
  setup %{conn: conn} do
    {:ok, conn: put_req_header(conn, "accept", "application/json")}
  end

  describe "create_task:" do
    test "create task", %{conn: conn} do
      %{ token: [ token ] } = get_poster_token(conn)
      conn = post(conn, Routes.item_path(conn, :create_all, @create_attrs))
      assert json_response(conn, 200)["status"] == 1
    end

  end

  defp get_poster_token(conn) do
    conn = post(conn, Routes.passwordless_path(conn, :user_auth, @user_poster))
    token = get_resp_header(conn, "authorization")
    %{token: token}
  end
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you please also show us the code from the test?

Comment: @TabKey I added my `exs` test file, and I simplified it for easy reading.

Comment: Try `post(conn, Routes.item_path(conn, :create_all), @create_attrs)`?

Comment: @Dogbert you are right. the actual code is `post(conn, Routes.item_path(conn, :create_all), item: @create_attrs)`. Thanks a lot. if you can put it as answer i will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the POST data as an argument to the routes function. It should be a separate argument to `post/3`:

```
post(conn, Routes.item_path(conn, :create_all), item: @create_attrs)
```